# JavaScript - Saving a HAR file based on a website URL to the location of the .js file

Tags: javascript, url, har

I have tried using Browsermod-proxy and fs but it keeps giving me errors about missing 'fsevents' or 'msgpack'. I've been looking and testing for at least a solid 15 hours and i cant seem to find anything.

Comment: Why don't you just use your browser's developer tools, or something like Fiddler?  Elaborate a bit... what are you trying to do?  What's the context?

Comment: Im looking to make this automatic. so i dont have to touch anything. what im looking to do exactly would be like this: i can click on my html document and whern i click it it will save the har file based on a set url and save the file to the same location as the html document.